# Powershell for reading outlook messages

Tags: powershell, outlook

I have been trying to read outlook messages in a inbox with a specific subject and download the attachments associated with that particular subject.
This is the powershell script which i have used

```
$filepath = “C:\folder”
 $filter="[Subject]=Test Powershell"
 Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | out-null 
 $olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders" -as [type]  
 $outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application 
 $namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI") 
 $namespace.Logon("profilename","mypassword",$false,$false)
 $folder = $namespace.getDefaultFolder($olFolders::olFolderInBox)
#$folder.items|select *
$folder.items.Restrict($filter)| 
  select -Expand Attachments | % {
    for ($i = $_.Count; $i; $i--) {
      $_.Item($i).SaveAsFile("$filepath\$($_.Item($i).FileName)")
    }
  }
```

However after the outlook MAPI object was created, I was prompted with the profile password to be provided manually even though I have added `$namespace.Logon` with profile password as a paramater. I want the password of the profile to be sent through the script without password prompt.
Please point out the change that has to be made to do so.

Comment: According to [The Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861594.aspx) the password field of the `Logon()` method is deprecated and will not work on a modern system configuration.  it appears that if you are using the default profile the `Logon()` method can be removed but you probably want to do a bit more reading to ensure that this method will work for your specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

Namespace.Logon does not take the password for your Exchange mailbox. It might work for a password protected PST file, but not for an Exchange mailbox. Login in at least once and make sure "remember password" checkbox is checked to make sure you are no longer prompted.